# Increase max_bucket to 60,000 or make an msearch of 6 queries returning 10,000 buckets each in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES query that does this. It's a bunch of terms aggregations. (group by = terms) :

```
filter by date from year 2015 to 2020
  group by region
    group by date from year 2015 to 2020
    group by country
      group by date from year 2015 to 2020
      group by city
        group by date from year 2015 to 2020
          group by sales name
            group by date from year 2015 to 2020
```

the output looks like this. These are the sales broken down by region, country, person and year :

```
Region          Country         City        Name      2O15    2016  2017  2018  2019  2020

America                                               4000    8000  4000  6000  2000  4000
                
                United States                         2000    4000  2000  3000  1000  2000     
                                
                                New York              1000    2000  1000  1500  500   1000     
                                            
                                            James     500     1000  500   750   250   500     
                                            
                                            John      500     1000  500   750   250   500     

                                Los Angeles           1000    2000  1000  1500  500   1000     
                                            
                                            James     500     1000  500   750   250   500     
                                            
                                            John      500     1000  500   750   250   500 
                
                Mexico                                2000    4000  2000  3000  1000  2000     
                                
                                Mexico                1000    2000  1000  1500  500   1000     
                                            
                                            James     500     1000  500   750   250   500     
                                            
                                            John      500     1000  500   750   250   500     

                                guadalajara           1000    2000  1000  1500  500   1000     
                                            
                                            James     500     1000  500   750   250   500     
                                            
                                            John      500     1000  500   750   250   500
```

Problem : I hit a max_bucket limit because the limit is 10,000, it turns out I need 60,000 buckets.
Details :

- this requirement is non negotiable. It has to be returned like this
- I tried to limit requirements to only load one level at a time, but we have a download button where we have to retrieve the whole data anyway.
- it's not cachable unfortunately, because this report depends on p parameters that can each have n values. caching it would mean we cache more than 1000 variations.
  So right now I see two options :

increase max_buckets to 60000.
query the tree step by step in an msearch.
Here are the pros and cons for each options

- 1 big query that returns 60,000 buckets:

  - Pro :

    - simpler
  - Con :

    - higher payload
- an msearch of 6 small queries that each return 10,000 buckets and then rebuild the tree from there.

  - Pro :

    - smaller payload because less buckets
  - Con :

    - The backend will have to rebuild the tree from each msearch result of 10,000 buckets, and I am wondering if Elasticsearch is not better at doing this on its own.
    - More complex

1. Do you have a pro / con to add ?
2. Which option do you recommend ?
3. Do you recommend other options ?

Comment: This isn't really on topic, IMO. This depends entirely on your data. You're also assuming there are only two options, when you could break things down even further by country, year, users in that country, or a combination. I'd personally do this as a background job and write results to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I would use search_after:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html

=> You wont have to rebuild the tree, and would be almost the same on es side.